# Invoke Prime faces autoComplete and set the search text

Tags: primefaces, autocomplete

I have a prime faces autoComplete pojo with custom converter and it is working perfect.
I however would like to fire/call/invoke the autoComplete by code from another component.
Is there a way one can set the autoComplete search text without typing it?

Thank you.

Wence Benda

Comment: I need help on this issue. Please any one with a solution. Thanks

Comment: The problem is that you've posted no code to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the autocomplete's Javascript API to fire the search from another component. So, take for example, you have a command button and the autocomplete field.

```
<p:autoComplete id="acSimple" widgetVar="completeField" value="#{autoCompleteBean.txt1}" completeMethod="#{autoCompleteBean.complete}"/>  

<p:commandButton action="#{bean.test}" oncomplete="completeField.search('searchValue')" value="Test" update="completeField" />
```

The `search()` function will take a text argument that will execute the search function on the autocomplete field.

Comment: thanks. I tried your idea and it  works, i wana figure out how to dynamically replace the 'SearchValue' with a JSF inputbox's value. I have tried this oncomplete="completeField.search('#{transactionItem.itemCode}')" but am still not getting the best out of it. Thanks

Comment: @Wence Confirm the HTML that's generated is what you're expecting and that your backing bean/page variable `transactionItem` is in a scope that'll preserve the value long enough for the oncomplete to have it. Other than that, just use the javascript alternative to pass the value `clientId.value`